# What is the translation of this code to OpenCV Java?

Tags: java, c++, c, opencv

This code is OpenCV c++:

```
lines = cvHoughCircles(frame2, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 50, 300, 60, 10, 600);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.total(); i++) {
    //Would like the code to go here
     CvPoint2D32f point = new CvPoint2D32f(cvGetSeqElem(lines, i));
     cvCircle(src, cvPoint((int)point.x(), (int)point.y()), 3, CvScalar.WHITE, -1, 8, 0);
     Point p = new Point((int)point.x(), (int)point.y());
     points.add(p);
}
```

What is the correspondent in the new Java Api? I cannot get `CvPoint2D32f`, `cvGetSeqElem` and `CV_AA`. I found that existed in JavaCV but cannot find them in OpenCV Java api.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I've changed my code and now I have:

```
MatOfPoint3 circles = new MatOfPoint3();
Imgproc.HoughCircles(image, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,2, image.rows()/4,200,100,0,0);
for(Point3 circle : circles.toArray()){
     Point center = new Point(circle.x, circle.y);
     int radius = (int) Math.round(circle.z);      
     Core.circle(image, center, radius, new Scalar(0,255,0), 6, 8, 0);    
}
```

However I got an error at `for(Point3 circle : circles.toArray())`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Mat data type is not compatible: 21
     at org.opencv.core.Mat.get(Mat.java:2581)
     at org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint3.toArray(MatOfPoint3.java:64)
     at org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint3.toList(MatOfPoint3.java:76)
     at main.java.DetectFaceDemo.run(HelloOpenCV.java:60)
at main.java.HelloOpenCV.main(HelloOpenCV.java:83)
```

Any thoughts on this? Thanks

**EDIT 2:**

The solution to last edit problem resides in
         `MatOfPoint3 circles = new MatOfPoint3();`

It must be 
    `MatOfPoint3f circles = new MatOfPoint3f();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Class Point3. Template class for 3D points specified by its coordinates x, y and z. An instance of the class is interchangeable with the C structure CvPoint2D32f. Similarly to Point_, the coordinates of 3D points can be converted to another type. The vector arithmetic and comparison operations are also supported.

Comment: And what about `cvGetSeqElem` and `CV_AA`? I cannot find them. Thanks

Comment: Guess I don't need `cvGetSeqElem`.
I have this :

     `for(Point3 circle : circles.toArray()){
         Point center = new Point(circle.x, circle.y);
         int radius = (int) Math.round(circle.z);      
         Core.circle(image, center, radius, new Scalar(0,255,0), 6, CV_AA, 0);    
        }`
now only `CV_AA` is missing